# Spinners in my layout is over lapping the text-view

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-spinner, overlap

Hey guys/girls Im creating a food tracker app for a class project. Where the user adds a spinner that has an array of items "food".

Problem: when the user adds  6 food in the breakfast section it over laps the next section which would be lunch. How would I fix this? I tried doing it in a listview but had problems.

content_main.xml

```
        <ScrollView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:text="@string/breakfast"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="127dp"
        android:text="Lunch"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:paddingBottom="130dp"
        android:text="@string/dinner"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/LLL"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/LLL"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/BLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:id="@+id/bkSpinner"
            android:layout_weight="0.21"
            android:entries="@array/allFoodItems" />






    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/addNewDItem"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:id="@+id/LSpinner"
            android:layout_weight="0.21"
            android:entries="@array/allFoodItems"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addNewLItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="@string/LButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addNewDItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="@string/DButton" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/DLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/LLL"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/LLL"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addNewDItem">


        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:id="@+id/dnSpinner"
            android:entries="@array/allFoodItems" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/calories"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/total"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/addNewDItem"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/addNewDItem"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textSize="12dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/total"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="@string/totalCal" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addNewBItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/BButton"
        android:layout_column="13"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/BLL"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addNewDItem"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/addNewDItem" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

design your xml 'row by row' using `LinearLayout`  :

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="BrekFast"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:id="@+id/bkSpinner"
            android:layout_weight="0.21"
            ...  />
        <Button
            android:text="Add Breakfast"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ...  />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="BrekFast"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:id="@+id/bkSpinner2"
            android:layout_weight="0.21"
        ...  />
        <Button
            android:text="Add Breakfast"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...  />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="BrekFast"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:id="@+id/bkSpinner3"
            android:layout_weight="0.21"
        ...  />
        <Button
            android:text="Add Breakfast"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...  />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Calories Total"/>



</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```